# Find the number of solutions of the equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have tried to figure this one out but I just can't seem to get it. I have the answer but I don't understand the method/thinking behind this. Please explain how to:

Find the number of solutions of the equation: 
$$2\sqrt{3} \arctan\sqrt x =\sqrt{(1 + x)}$$

I'm pretty sure the method doesn't matter but the given solution is here:
[pdf solution](https://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/%7Efigurny/www/?download=p2.pdf) (download link, sorry it's just the way it is. The 2nd link is a screenshot of it)

If someone could explain I would be very grateful.

[I'm not yet allowed to add images but this is the link generated by THIS SITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBFdZ.jpg)

Comment: its \sqrt{x} in between $ $

Comment: I'm sorry, when you wrote $\arctan(x)^{1/2}$, did you mean $\sqrt{\arctan(x)}$ or $\arctan(\sqrt x)$? I might've made the wrong call when editing.

Comment: its 2sqrt3 arctan sqrtx

Comment: @Arthur I think you changed the equation when you edited it. I believe Rose is trying to solve $2\sqrt{3}\arctan\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{1+x}$.

Comment: Do you know Calculus? The solution provided in the pdf file uses Calculus...

Comment: @TimThayer I realized that. It's just that when it says `arctan(x)^(1/2)` instead of, say, `arctan(x^(1/2))`, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: I'm still learning calculus but I know it a bit. (This is my university question) The problem is I have basic high school math so this is a big jump for me

Comment: Does the solution contain a closed form or just the numerical value ?

Comment: Just the number of solutions, so in this case it's 2

Comment: The link to the PDF is somewhat unfriendly: normally, to provide a PDF file, one just has the URL of the file itself rather than a "?download=" query. Trying to view this on my phone, I just see a blank screen. Usually we prefer that the essential parts of any external resource are reproduced in the text of the question; but if that's too much, is there a better link to the file?

Comment: I'm not going to read through an external pdf.  Put the relevant parts in the post as text.

Comment: There's nothing scary about a PDF, the problem is with the way the website delivers it. Thousands of web sites deliver PDFs in the most convenient way, but whoever set up _that_ site decided to make other people's lives more difficult than they needed to be. The screenshot works much better.

Comment: Okay, now can anyone explain how to get the solution? Pretty please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps.

First, we notice that $2\sqrt{3} \arctan\sqrt x =\sqrt{1 + x}$
is exactly equivalent to the statement
$$(2\sqrt{3} \arctan\sqrt x) - \sqrt{1 + x} = 0.$$
The left side of that equation is a function of $x.$
So if we define
$$f(x) = (2\sqrt{3} \arctan\sqrt x) - \sqrt{1 + x},$$
then the solutions of the original equation are just the values of $x$
that satisfy $f(x) = 0.$
That lets us start applying techniques that are generally useful for counting the solutions to equations of the form $f(x) = 0.$

What the answer sheet shown in the question concludes is that
$f(0) < 0,$ $f(3) > 0,$ and $f(x) < 0$ for large values of $x$;
moreover, $f$ is continuous, so somewhere between $x=0$ and $x=3$
there is at least one solution (the graph of $f(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis),
and there is at least one more solution for some $x$ greater than $3.$

In order to show that there is *only* one solution in each of those regions
(so only two solutions altogether), and also to decide that we should look at $f(x)$ when $x=3,$ the answer sheet computes the derivative of $f,$
$$ f'(x) = \frac{\sqrt3}{(1+x)\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}. $$
It then does some algebra to figure out where $f'(x)$ is positive and where it is negative.
It determines that $f'(x)$ is positive whenever $(x+4)(x-3) < 0.$
In general, that inequality is equivalent to $-4 < x < 3,$ but
since $f$ and $f'$ are not defined for $x < 0,$ we only need to worry about what happens for $x \geq 0$; so the facts we need to know are that $f'(x)>0$ when $0\leq x<3,$ $f'(3) = 0,$ and $f'(x) < 0$ when $x > 3.$
The answer sheet states these facts graphically by presenting a rough sketch of the graph of $f'(x).$
These facts also imply that $f$ will have a maximum value at $x=3,$
so $f(3)$ is a good place to look in order to find a positive value of $f(x).$ And indeed $f(3)> 0.$

So we know that $f(x)=0$ at least once between $x=0$ and $x=3,$
and because $f(x)$ is *increasing* over that entire interval, it can only have one zero in that interval. That is, we have exactly one solution (no more, no less) for some $x$ in the interval $0 < x < 3.$
We also know that $f(x)=0$ at least once for $x>3,$
and because $f(x)$ is *decreasing* over that entire interval, it can only have one zero in that interval. So we have exactly one solution for some $x$ such that $x > 3.$ Therefore there are exactly two solutions.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.